# Sitecore Bucket Manager in Sitecore 9.1

Tags: upgrade, buckets

I'm migrating my Sitecore 8.1 solution to Sitecore 9.1.

The Sitecore.Buckets.Managers assembly is not supported anymore. What should I use to still deal with my buckets ? Is there any replacement of BucketManager ?

```csharp
foreach (Item assetLibrary in assetLibraries)
{
    if (BucketManager.IsBucket(assetLibrary))
    {
        BucketManager.Sync(assetLibrary);
    }
    searchIndex.Refresh((IIndexable)assetLibrary, IndexingOptions.ForcedIndexing);
}
```

#### Update: Content added from OP:

Yes, but the issue is that I cannot install the Sitecore.Buckets.dll version 9.1.1 in my solution :

> Could not install package 'Sitecore.Buckets 9.1.1'. You are trying to
> install this package into a project that targets
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7', but the package does not contain any
> assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
> framework. For more information, contact the package author.

And my solution needs .NET 4.7 Framework...

Comment: In Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketManager I can still see the IsBucket and Sync methods (in a 9.1 version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore.Buckets.Manager is present Sitecore.Buckets.dll assembly in Sitecore 9.1.

You don't need to do any changes in your code. Just, reference right assembly.

Sitecore 9.1 requires .net 4.7.1. See: https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore

Comment: Thank you, you were right, the BucketManager is compatible with .NET Framework 4.7.1. I had to edit my packages.config files in all the projects of my solution.